# PHP extract html tag value into array from string

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to extract value of each html tag  from my string into array. This is my str value:

```
str = '<li><a href="/somelink1">name1</a></li><li><a href="/somelink2">name2</a></li><li><a href="/somelink3">name3</a></li>'
```

I want to extract each name (name1, name2, name3) and put it into array. So the output should be:

```
output = Array(
           [0] => 'name1',
           [1] => 'name2',
           [2] => 'name3'
         )
```

I was looking for some function that may do something similar, but no luck at all :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use html parser for that

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$lis = [];
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {
    $lis[] =  $li->nodeValue;
}

print_r($lis); // Array ( [0] => name1 [1] => name2 [2] => name3 )
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you very much, working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do it and **regex** is one of them. You can try like this way with [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
<?php
$re = '/<a ?.*?>([^<]+)<\/a>/m';
$str = '<li><a href="/somelink1">name1</a></li><li><a href="/somelink2">name2</a></li><li><a href="/somelink3">name3</a></li>';
$result = [];
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
foreach($matches as $match){
    $result[] = $match[1];
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( 
  [0] => name1 
  [1] => name2 
  [2] => name3 
)
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/B7k58

**REGEX**: https://regex101.com/r/HPDhtA/1

Comment: Thank you, I was trying with regex before but I could not get it, your solution also works but I see @splash58 solution as more clear.

Comment: Ok @Steve glat it helps you somehow. By the way see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Actually @splash58 answer is in right direction but he might miss the actual requirement i.e. only Name value not links, if I'm not wrong.
So just try this

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$names = [];
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    $names[] =  $a->nodeValue;
}

print_r($names);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I was looking only for names of those links (<a>).

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of an xpath expression using [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and specify exactly what you want to find:

`//li/a`

For example:

```
$str = '<li><a href="/somelink1">name1</a></li><li><a href="/somelink2">name2</a></li><li><a href="/somelink3">name3</a></li>';
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = [];
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//li/a') as $a) {
    $result[] = $a->nodeValue;
}

print_r($result);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => name1
    [1] => name2
    [2] => name3
)
```